# DllImport and return parameters

Tags: pinvoke

I am working on hardware testing. Our test framework is written in C# but we are using native dlls to talk to hardware.

Say we have a C++ method:

```cs
unsigned char someMethod(unsigned long * nativeStatus)
```

which in turns executes an embedded command and returns a status when command completes.

To use it we create a wrapper

```cs
[DllImport(@"native.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static extern Byte someMethod(ref UInt32 managedStatus)
```

This works fine. But there is a scenario when `someMethod` call does not actually execute a command but just adds it to a sequence. Then the sequence can be executed by sending a special command say `ExecuteSequence`. As the sequence is being executed C++ code  updates the `nativeStatus` by just copying the data into the memory referenced by the `nativeStatus` pointer. As the sequence completes `ExecuteSequence` method returns. At this time I am sure that all data (`nativeStatus` in this case) is updated. Will my `managedStatus` be correctly updated as well? I heard that in this case `managedStatus` and `nativeStatus` are not pointing to the same memory. Marshaler just returns a copy of `nativeState` after call completes. If not what is the solution? Do I need to use the unsave keyword and put my code creating and executing a sequence in the `fixed{}` block?

```cs
[DllImport(@"native.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
internal static unsave extern Byte someMethod(UInt32 * managedStatus)
```

Comment: Are you saying that `someMethod` can potentially kcik off a background execution and you want to access the status as it runs?  Or is `someMethod` always a blocking call that, in the course of its work, sets a status code upon exit?

Answer (score 0):

So what you need is a variable location of which will not change over a timespan.

Yes, you can use `fixed{}` for that.
Alternatively, you can pin that variable:

```cs
private uint g_Pinnable = 0;

...

var gc = System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.Alloc(g_Pinnable, System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandleType.Pinned);

try
{
    // Pass 'ref g_Pinnable' to API
    // Then execute the sequence.
}
finally
{
    gc.Free(); // Reference to g_Pinnable may be invalid after this point
}
```